# SQL Server unexplained deadlocks events

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

We are using Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Standard Edition (64-bit) on AWS and we are suffering from unexplained deadlocks events.

We are trying to update different unique rows from a different processes, the table and page escalation is disabled, the sqlserver using key lock and we still get a deadlock.

The data in the profiler showed that each process worked on a different row, so we do not understand why this deadlock occurred.

**
We think that we managed to reproduce this deadlock in test tables ,but we still don't have an explanation for this deadlock (table and page escalation is disabled).

```sql
CREATE TABLE TestTable 
( 
ID CHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Val CHAR(1) 
) 

--in session 1 
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
  DECLARE @INX bigint ;
  DECLARE @INX2 nchar(8);

  SET @INX = NEXT VALUE FOR SequenceExample ; 
  

  set @INX2 = @INX;

  Print (@INX2)

  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
 
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]
           ([ID]
           ,[Val])
     VALUES
           (@INX2,'Y');

  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05' 

  UPDATE [dbo].[TestTable] 
  SET Val='X' 
  WHERE ID= @INX2
  
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05' 
  
  COMMIT ;

--in session 2 
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
  DECLARE @INX bigint ;
  DECLARE @INX2 nchar(8);

  SET @INX = NEXT VALUE FOR SequenceExample ; 
  

  set @INX2 = @INX;

  Print (@INX2)

  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
 
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]
           ([ID]
           ,[Val])
     VALUES
           (@INX2,'Y');

  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05' 

  UPDATE [dbo].[TestTable] 
  SET Val='X' 
  WHERE ID= @INX2
  
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05' 
  
  COMMIT ;
```

Comment: Are you able to [capture the XML deadlock graph](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/capturing-deadlock-information/) and share it?

Comment: Are there any other indexes on the table? Triggers?

Comment: @AMtwo I added the graph

Comment: @ErikDarling There's another non-clustered unique index that includes two fields (Id and Val), no triggers.

Comment: Can you add the definition for the Sequence

Comment: CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[SequenceExample] 
 AS [bigint]
 START WITH 73618
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE -9223372036854775808
 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
 CACHE  5 
GO

Comment: what's the purpose of this ? set @ INX = cast(@ INX as char(8));
The Sequence & @INX are bigint ? But the column in the table is defined as char(8).
Why do you need the insert & the update in the same transaction ? 
Do you know what transaction isolation level you are using ?

Comment: We are working in isolation level read committed snapshot on.
The column is defined as char(8) for historical reasons.
"update in the same transaction" good point, need to check with the application team.

set @ INX = cast(@ INX as char(8)); is just an attempt to convert to the same data type that the column has .you will get the deadlock error without this converting.

but conceptually, why I'm getting deadlock in sqlserver when I'm executing my code in two different sessions when table and page escalation is disabled?

Comment: What is the definition for that non-clustered index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the deadlock issue was caused by a mismatch between the column data type char(8) and the variable datatype nchar(8) .
the mismatch forced that DB to convert the data which led to deadlock when two transactions started at the same time, although that each one of them worked on another record.
the issue was solved after we update the column datatype to nchar .(same as the variable )